# What is the meaning of public and tags at the declaration of extension Twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

What is the meaning of public and tags at the declaration of extension Twig?

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html#register-an-extension-as-a-service

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.twig_extension:
        class: AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension
        public: false
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

What is public and tags? What I can I use it?

Answer (score 0):

In the Symfony Docs [Marking Services as Public / Private](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/advanced.html#marking-services-as-public-private):

> What makes private services special is that, if they are only injected
>   once, they are converted from services to inlined instantiations (e.g.
>   new PrivateThing()). This increases the container's performance.
>
> Now that the service is private, you should not fetch the service
>   directly from the container:

Basically private services are only available for injection into other services. You wouldn't be able to fetch the service in your controller action for instance.

```
$container->get('app.twig_extension'); // would fail
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional information:

Tagging is just used for grouping and manipulating the same kind of services before compilation of the service container. That's it, nothing special. Here are very useful posts:

- [Symfony2 service container: how to make your service use tags](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2011/10/symfony2-service-container-how-to-make-your-service-use-tags/) (this post has been included to the official documentation given below)
- [DependencyInjection component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/index.html)

For example, if you create your own class (by extending the base `Twig_Extension` class), declare it as a service and tag it as `twig.extension` and clear the caches (with warming up), Twig compiler pass class (`TwigEnvironmentPass` class) automatically registers it and recognize it like its own extensions, which you can use in your twig template files..